# Is this a grammatical sentence?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, sentence, syntactic-analysis

One of my students wrote a sentence, shown hereunder in italics, and I can't seem to be able to tell if it is correct or not?
*Andrew has thought good of creating some company and setting it up abroad.*

Here's the larger context:

"Hey, Jake, hold on a second. I've got something to tell you."

"What now, Marry?", sighed Jake.

"I think Fred's gone and gotten himself in quite a lot of trouble..."

"How come?" Jake put in, briskly.

"Well, as you know Fred's been talkin' about how he's tired of working for slave-wages and how there's no chance in hell he's going to die in poverty forever now. And guess what he did today!? He quit his job, you know the one that your brother got him after he got out of jail, and then he said to me: "Andrew has thought *good* of creating some company and setting it up abroad. I don't know what it is, but he's going to pay me 30 grand to go to South America and set it up for him down there. Andrew gave an advance. 10 grand. But, I am gonna need your help, sis. Can you come along with me? I mean, I am going to need someone who can speak Spanish well down there."

Comment: **Proofreading questions ("Is this correct?", "Are there any mistakes?")** or critique requests are off-topic unless a specific source of concern in the text is clearly identified. Please edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence provided, *Andrew has thought good of creating some company and setting it up abroad,* can be considered incorrect on a number of grounds. It would not be recognized as fluent English by a native speaker of the language.

*Andrew has thought **well*** might pass muster, as would *Andrew has thought **it good to create***.

In either case, **thought** is not a linking (copulative) verb, and so cannot take an adjective complement (*good*.)

***Some company*** is also problematic.  In context, it appears that Andrew has given some thought to creating ***a*** company.  If he has gone this far in his thinking, it seems unlikely that he would be considering something so vague as creating "***some company or other***," even though that's what the use of **some** would imply.

*The sentence is what my friends in the southern US would call "a big hot mess," and should be recognized as such at first glance.*

Comment: *Andrew thought well of* wouldn't pass muster either since *to think well of* is an idiomatic expression meaning to think highly of, and it's clear that "Andrew has thought hard about" his commercial adventure.  *Good*, no; *hard*, yes.  How does anyone learn this language?

Comment: @deadrat - Good point.  As to your rhetorical question, evidently they don't. As the famous Quaker saying goes, " "Me thinks the whole world is crazy except me and thee; and sometimes I wonder about thee."  (The Famous Quaker was probably a founding member of EL&U.)  ;-)

Comment: I don't see any problem with "some" though. Also, I have provided some additional context to this "hot big mess". But honestly, I just don't know. I still have a few reservations. I mean, it just doesn't seem to me as something that should be recognized as "a big hot mess"  at first glance. By the way, the story whence this sentence comes is set in the southern US in the late 70s.

Comment: But then again, maybe you are right. Maybe I just got too close to this to see it for what it is... I am going to sleep on it before I make up my mind.